# How to write an unicode string in 2 forms (string and binary) to the registry?

Tags: mfc, registry, winapi

I have a dialog based program. It has a edit box where I get input from user. I have to write the input unicode string to registry in 2 forms, in string form using REG_SZ and in binary form(utf-8 HEXA) using REG_BINARY. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
CString txt;
    m_wndEdit.GetWindowText(txt);

    HKEY key;
    HKEY    KeySet   = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyExW(KeySet,_T("Software\\MyApp"),0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&key))
    {       
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS == 
            RegSetValueExW(key, _T("MyParamSZ"), 0,REG_SZ, (BYTE*)txt.GetString(), txt.GetLength()))
        {

        }
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS == 
            RegSetValueExW(key, _T("MyParamBIN"), 0,REG_BINARY, (BYTE*)txt.GetString(), txt.GetLength() * sizeof(WCHAR)))
        {

        }
RegCloseKey(key);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I still have problem. When I write my unicode string to registry, I want to write it in the form of utf-8 hexadecimal, but your solution save the hexa unicode. Do you have any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CString you could use std::wstring - here is an example where an integer is transformed into a wstring and then put into registry REG_SZ key.

```
bool SetRegistryKeyValue(int NewSetting) const
{
    bool result = false;
    HKEY hkey = nullptr;
    std::wstring str = std::to_wstring(NewSetting);


    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, STRING_REGISTRY_KEY, 0, KEY_WRITE, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RegSetValueExW(hkey, STRING_REGISTRY_VALUE, NULL, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)str.c_str(), str.size());
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```